# What does "It's all in where you are standing" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, figurative-language

I was reading the novel *A Song of Ice and Fire* and this phrase came up twice and I don't get what it means at all.

> “Winterfell’s not in the south,” Jon objected.
> “Yes it is. Everything below the Wall’s south to us.”
> He had never thought of it that way. **“I suppose it’s all in where you’re standing.”**
> “Aye,” Ygritte agreed. “It always is.”

> “Well, long before he was king over the free folk, Bael was a great raider.”
> Stonesnake gave a snort. “A murderer, robber, and raper, is what you mean.”
> **“That’s all in where you’re standing too,”** Ygritte said

Comment: Where you are standing gives your [point of view](https://www.lexico.com/definition/point_of_view).

Answer (score 1):

Think of this: You stand **in or at a location**. If you're standing at the bottom of a ravine or at the top of a hill, you will see things differently.

Your point of viewing of what surrounds you will change.

It is also used as a metaphor. You are not literally standing anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What something is or means may depend on what you bring to the question - your own history or prejudices. That's summarized in the phrase "where you are standing".